# XPath expression to select self, Parents and following nodes based on node attribute c#

Tags: c#, xpath

Need xPath to select all [aqua] nodes for given Page[@ID='NeededPage']

[Please take a look at the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVO8e.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try :

```
 //Page[@ID='NeededPage']/descendant-or-self::* | //Page[@ID='NeededPage']/ancestor::*
```

Have a look to http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp